# Is there a name for when two numbers have the same sums of divisors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology, recreational-mathematics

If $a,b$ are integers and $\sigma$ is the sum of divisors function and $\sigma (a) = \sigma (b)$ is there a name for this?
For instance $\sigma (14) = \sigma (15) = 24$

Comment: Not that I know of, but the notion of 'friendliness' is similar in flavor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number

Answer (score 1):

Amicable numbers are also quite similar to what you are asking for, perhaps more similar than friendly numbers. You may also want to look at the aliquot sum (denoted as $s(n)=\sigma(n)-n$).

*Edit: One concept I have noticed that may aid the OP is the following:*

*If $\text{gcd}(n,k)=1$, then $\sigma(nk) = \sigma(n)\sigma(k)$.*

*So, if you know the prime factorisation of any number $s$, $\sigma(s)=\sigma(s_{p_1})\sigma(s_{p_2})\cdots\sigma(s_{p_n})$ (where $s_{p_n}$ denotes the $n$th prime factor of $s$.)*

Comment: Amicable numbers are exactly what the poster is lookin for, I think.  For example you have $\sigma(220) = \sigma(284) = 504$ and these are an amicable pair.

Comment: @MichaelLugo No, not exactly, because 14 and 15 are not amicable (since s(n) is used rather than (n) in the definition of amicable numbers).

Comment: You're right.  A pair of amicable numbers has $\sigma(a) = \sigma(b) = a+b$; the poster is just looking for $\sigma(a) = \sigma(b)$.